# Why _ (underscore) is not present in the list of java keywords?

Tags: java

When the following statement is compiled using Java 11, it says that '_' is a keyword and may not be used as an identifier.

```
int _ = 10;
```

If underscore is a keyword, then why it is not present in the list of java keywords mentioned at [Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is still on Java 8. If you want to follow more accurate and updated specification, you should take a look at the Java Language Specification, specifically [this section from Specification for Java SE 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

```
abstract   continue   for          new         switch
assert     default    if           package     synchronized
boolean    do         goto         private     this
break      double     implements   protected   throw
byte       else       import       public      throws
case       enum       instanceof   return      transient
catch      extends    int          short       try
char       final      interface    static      void
class      finally    long         strictfp    volatile
const      float      native       super       while
_ (underscore)
```

Comment: That's nowhere near "the most accurate and updated" version. SE 15 is the latest. See the index page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes OP was using JDK 11. Fixed that, thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the note on top of [the page you are referring to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) says it:

> The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases and might use technology no longer available.
> See [Java Language Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/java/javase&id=java_language_changes) for a summary of updated language features in Java SE 9 and subsequent releases.
> See [JDK Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-relnotes-index-2162236.html) for information about new features, enhancements, and removed or deprecated options for all JDK releases.

Apparently, they haven't (yet?) updated the tutorials to newer Java versions.

---

Even if it were allowed, I would suggest you not to be using the underscore character as a variable name anyway. Variable names should be descriptive.